# How to show original color of icon in Android Navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-menu

I created a new Android Studio project and seleced **Navigation drawer activity**

In **activity_main_drawer.xml** I changed the icon path to a file in drawable folder as below

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
    android:icon="@drawable/nav_logo_premium"
    android:title="Import" />
```

It changed the icon. but It does not show original color. It shows as **ash color**  I think I need to change the theme. after spending hours I could not find the solution.

I really appreciate any kind of help.

> Because i did not change code I did not attached all files source code
>   here

Please see attached screenshot
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Wne.png)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Force `NavigationView` to stop tinting the icons in *MainActivity.java*:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create style like this in your styles.xml

```
<style name="drawStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/red</item>
</style>
```

Add created style in to your main theme this change color of toggle button.

```
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/drawStyle</item>
```

If  You using Design Support library, you can change the icon colours using  `app:itemIconTint` property:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:itemIconTint="#f00"
    app:itemTextColor="#0f0"
    app:menu="@menu/left_menu" />
```

Comment: It did not work.. it changed color of left upper corner 3 line icon  only

Comment: Please see attached screenshot

Comment: Use app:itemIconTint property to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  **android:fillColor="#FF000000"**
from *V21/ic_menu_slideshow.xml*  **IF AVAILABLE**